# Which logging module to use under Perl's AnyEvent?

Tags: perl, asynchronous

I am using the wonderful [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent/) for creating an asynchronous TCP server (specifically, a MUD server).

In order to keep everything running smoothly and with as few blocking/synchronous pieces of code possible, I have replaced some modules I was using with their asynchronous counterpart, for example [AnyEvent::Memcached](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent-Memcached/) and [AnyEvent::Gearman](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent-Gearman/). This allows the main program to be quite speedy, which is desirable. I have coded around the need for some of these calls to be synchronous.

One problem I currently have, and the focus of this question, is logging.

Before turning to AnyEvent for this server program, I was using [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl/) as it allows me to fine-tune which modules or subroutines should be logged, at which level and to which log output (screen, file, etc).

The problem here is that the Log4perl actions (warn, info, etc) are currently performed synchronously but I have no requirement for that as long as the log lines eventually end up on the screen / file (and in the correct order).

Is Log::Log4perl still the right choice when using an asynchronous event handler such as AnyEvent, or should I look at a different module? If so, which is recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnyEvent::Log, which comes with AnyEvent, uses AnyEvent::IO, which appends to files asynchronously when IO::AIO is available (and synchronously when not).

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to avoid? If it's synchronous file IO (writing to log files/stdout etc.) then your problem would probably be solved with an asynchronous and/or buffering appender(s) rather than replacing all use of Log4perl in your code.

[Log::Log4perl::Appender::Buffer](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.31/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender/Buffer.pm) seems like it might be a good start, but a completely async appender doesn't appear to exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that an async appender doesn't seem to exist